# Docker compose ECS AWS Application Load balance redirect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

Im deploying my docker container via my docker compose file.

When i initially deploy my app it creates a load balancer but as type "network". I cannot do a redirect to https with this type.

I want my load balancer to be created as a type "application" and then setup the redirect from http to https.

My container will still be listening to port 80.

Bonus: i would like to deploy and also attach my SSL cert in my compose file so that its all ready on a fresh deploy.

As you can see ive tried a few things but cant get it to work.

Thanks

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  web:
    container_name: auction_web
    image: <ECR Image>
#    x-aws-pull_credentials: arn:aws:secretsmanager:xxxxxxxxxxxx
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ports:

#      - "80:80" - tried this
#      - "443:443" - tried this
      - target: 80
        x-aws-protocol: http
      - target: 443
        x-aws-protocol: https
#      - published: 80
#        protocol: "http"
#        x-aws-alb-default-actions:
#          - type: redirect
#            host: '<domain>'
#            port: 443
#            protocol: HTTPS
#            status-code: HTTP_301

#      - published: 443
#        protocol: "https"
#        x-aws-acm-certificate: <cert name>
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4096M
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow this? https://techsparx.com/software-development/docker/docker-ecs/load-balancer/https.html

Comment: indeed. Doesnt like those parameters when i do a docker compose up .

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

1. Define ports with "80:80" and "443:443" and nothing else.
2. Add the following section at the bottom of the docker-compose file:

```
x-aws-cloudformation:
  Resources:
    Web443Listener:
      Properties:
        Certificates:
          - CertificateArn: "<certificate ARN>"
        Protocol: HTTPS
        Port: 443
    Web80Listener:
      Properties:
        DefaultActions:
          - Type: redirect
            RedirectConfig:
              Port: 443
              Protocol: HTTPS
              StatusCode: HTTP_301
```

Comment: thank you for this. i modified a bit but i have more control over the compose up to ecs this way so i made the whole yml file the raw template. Is this the right way to go in terms of best practise? or should i remove everything docker related and start using the aws cli to deploy

Answer (score 0):

```
x-aws-cloudformation:
  Resources:
    App80Listener:
      Properties:
        Port: 80
        Protocol: HTTP
        LoadBalancerArn:
          Ref: LoadBalancer
        DefaultActions:
          - Type: redirect
            RedirectConfig:
              Port: 443
              Protocol: HTTPS
              StatusCode: HTTP_301
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener

    App443Listener:
      Properties:
        Port: 443
        Protocol: HTTPS
        LoadBalancerArn:
          Ref: LoadBalancer
        DefaultActions:
          - ForwardConfig:
              TargetGroups:
                - TargetGroupArn:
                    Ref: App8080TargetGroup
            Type: forward
        Certificates:
          - CertificateArn: "<arn for cert>"
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener

    App8080TargetGroup:
      Properties:
        Name: 'jenkins-tg'
        Port: 8080
        Protocol: HTTP
        Tags:
          - Key: com.docker.compose.project
            Value: jenkins
        TargetType: ip
        VpcId: vpc-d21afbbb
        HealthCheckPath: '/login'
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
```